# Create different environments for ASP.NET Core 2.0 app

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment

I want to create *Staging* and *Production* versions of my **appsettings.json** configuration but can't see exactly how to do this.

I can see that there is an **appsettings.Development.json** file in my project, and that there is an environment variable called **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** that is set to *Development*.

Presumably I need to create **appsettings.Stage.json** and **appsettings.Production.json** and set the value for **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** accordingly?

If so, how would I set the value of **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** in my release pipeline? I check in code with the *Development* settings, but these will need to be changed when I release to our *Staging* and *Production* environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually an environment variable in OS. 
For Windows you can set it via command line: `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Production"`
or with PowerShell `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Production"`

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for other OS.

Comment: That article explains everything I need. Thanks very much :)